# how to change my homepage for EC2 instance

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

i recently set up an EC2 instance and installed apache, mysql, php and other things on the server. my public ip works on a web browser and yields

It works!

This is the default web page for this server.

The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.

How do I change this? my site is under construction and in development and want to just put an image of our logo and state that its under constuction? any idea where the file is that i would need to change??? thanks

Answer (score 1):

In some Linux installs, you should change the `index.html` file to whatever static page you want located in `/var/www/` which is apache's default root directory. If you are using Amazon Linux AMI, place an index.html in `/var/www/html` Or if it's Windows-based server look for `C:\Program Files\Apache Group\Apache2\htdocs`

Comment: its a ubuntu based server on AWS....sorry if im a little slow, fairly new to this. when i go to the var directory there isnt even a www/ path. any idea where the default is for apache to save the default homepage

Comment: or better asked where is the index.html file saved?

Comment: ok i see i there, but how do i go about editing it? i only see it when in terminal but not within filezilla

Comment: If you aren't familiar with unix/vim/nano it's going to be tough to explain. The only thing I can recommend now is to find a secure ftp/secure copy client so you can upload files to it.

Comment: got it thanks. yes i am using filezilla to manage uploading files to the server but can seem to pinpoint where the home page file is. when i get to the var folder there is now www folder with index.html. it does appear when i ssh in through terminal

Comment: As I've explained, yes, that index.html is the file you want to edit/change. The one located inside `var/www/`

Comment: Hey there, if this answer was helpful to you, would you mind casting a vote and select as answered, if you'd be so kind. Thanks.